# How to speed up seda shutdown?

Tags: java, apache-camel, shutdown

Is there any way to stop `SedaConsumer` without waiting for `BlockingQueue.take(pollTimeout, ...)` to return? I have a lot of sedas in my application and a graceful shutdown takes a lot of time. When `DefaultShutdownStrategy` shutdown `sedaConsumers` there are no more messages in the queue and no more messages will be produced (because of implementation of routes shutdown before). So each `sedaConsumer` has to wait about 1 second.

Is it possible to force doStop instead of prepareShutdown for seda? Or interrupt workers threads?

I know I can decrease `pollTimeout`, but I afraid it will affect runtime performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SedaConsumer.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/seda/SedaConsumer.java):

```
        try {
            // use the end user configured poll timeout
            exchange = queue.poll(pollTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            // Omitted
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.debug("Sleep interrupted, are we stopping? {}", isStopping() || isStopped());
            continue;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (exchange != null) {
                getExceptionHandler().handleException("Error processing exchange", exchange, e);
            } else {
                getExceptionHandler().handleException(e);
            }
        }
```

This construct is at most places in the thread where an InterruptedException can be thrown so if the consumer is stopping and is interrupted it will stop gracefully.